# How do you switch between "pages" of a Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am currently loading the default file, page.xaml, but in that page, I am loading the content from another xaml file.  With each "page" change, I just load the content from a different xaml file, and on and on.

Example:  this.Content = new StartPage();

I'm running into some syntax issues, however, because of the way I am changing my content, and was wondering if there is a definitive answer on how to accomplish this?

For example, when trying to capture user's keystrokes, I would normally do:

this.Keydown += new KeyEventHandler(this_KeyDown);

but that event handler doesn't even fire in my situation.  So, I'm looking for a new approach to my content-switching approach before revisiting the keystroke problem.

Comment: You might considered creating a separate question for the Keydown issue - it seems unrelated to navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using Silverlight 3.  It has a new Page Navigation functionality.[Silverlight 3 Navigation](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/22/silverlight-navigation-framework-and-uri-routing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as content switching goes, I've always done what you propose in the question.  Normally I create a MainPage.xaml which has has the frame of the application (usually a Grid for me).  One of the cells in the Grid is considered the content area of the app.  When the user takes an action that I would consider to be navigation, I create a new instance of a Page, which for me is a file like MyUserControl.xaml, and then add it to the appropriate content cell in the Grid.  MainPage stays around for the life of the application and assists with navigation.

If you want something fancier, and want to take advantage of browser based back/forward buttons, you could look into the SL3 navigation like Correl suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A Big problem with what your're doing is that journalization doesnt take place automatically when you swap out framework elements by creating them and plugging them in the codebehind. This means that you lose the back and forward functionality of the browser. You can manually journalize stuff when you swap out pages, but this is simply a hack to get your navigation approach working.

Take a look at Prism at www.compositewpf.codeplex.com/, specifically the MVVM method of GUI design, it'll save you alot of time later on. And remember, you dont need to go hardcore when you look at MVVM, u could always cut out alot of "dynamic" functionality if you're a one man band

Also swap to silverlight 3 and use the navigation application. If you cant, take a look at  [helix 0.3](http://blogs.msdn.com/dphill/archive/2009/04/28/silverlight-navigation-part-3.aspx), it'll provide a more asp oriented approach to navigation. the link provides a really really good starting point, its a three part article, i suggest you read all three and download the sample application and understand it.

A book could have been written on your question, this has to suffice for now.